# How do I get jQuery UI autocomplete to ignore punctuation, yet display it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the `jQuery UI autocomplete` to ignore punctuation.  I currently have an `array` of objects stored in `availableTags` that looks like :

```
 [{'label':'AA RS20.0-4', 'value':'AA RS2004'},
 {'label':'AA AF-20.0-5', 'value': 'AA AF2005'},
 {'label':'ALL 2000 SERIES', 'value':'ALL 2000 SERIES'},
 {'label':'ALL 2000MH', 'value':'ALL 2000MH'}]
```

Basically, I need to have the `autocomplete filter` by the value stored in value, but display the value stored in label.
My issue comes in when I type in `"200"`. Ideally, all results should display. 
My current code:

```
$('#entermod').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/, ""));
        console.log(results);
        response(results.slice(0, 10));},           
    minLength : 3
}).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
};
```

What do I need to change to get this to work? Or do I need to take a completely different approach to this situation?

Comment: Can you add a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, of all your above code seems to have errors.

1. It doesn't complete `'` and `}`.
2. You are going to use `jquery autocomplete` which takes source as:

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported
>   formats: An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ] An array of
>   objects with label and value properties:
>   [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Here the `label` is used as key and options displayed are `value`s.

So, in your code where I think `label` and `value` are interchanged, only two `label`s get matched with the filter.

So, here is your corrected code:

**JS**

```
var availableTags = 
[{'value':'AA RS20.0-4', 'label':'AA RS2004'},
 {'value':'AA AF-20.0-5', 'label': 'AA AF2005'},
 {'value':'ALL 2000 SERIES', 'label':'ALL 2000 SERIES'},
 {'value':'ALL 2000MH', 'label':'ALL 2000MH'}] ;

$('#entermod').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/, ""));
        console.log(results);
        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    },           
    minLength : 3
}).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.value + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
```

Take a look here and check if its working:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ4A3/2/)**